# purpose of the "function()" for attaching a function to a eventlistener

Tags: javascript

Sorry if the question looks stupid, but I have been confused for long time.

I want to alert "viola" when the button is clicked. 
The second example below doesn't work as expected because I didn't include "function()"

Intuitively I think the second example should be working since I have attached a function(allert) to the element(button) and eventlistener(onclick).

Therefore I really wondered the purpose of including function(). Thanks.

Example 1

```
<html>
<button id="clickme">Hello,I'm a button,click me</button>


<script>
    var button=document.getElementById("clickme");

    clickme.onclick=function() {alert("viola");}


</script>
</html>
```

Example 2

```
<html>
<button id="clickme">Hello,I'm a button,click me</button>


<script>
    var button=document.getElementById("clickme");

    clickme.onclick=alert("viola");


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Answer (score 3):

```
clickme.onclick=alert("viola");
```

doesn't register the function `alert(..)`, but the result of **calling** that function.

The `onclick` field expects a `function`, to be executed later, when the button is clicked. You don't want to execute that function when you're installing the handler.
You could also write:

```
clickme.onclick=myfunction;

function myfunction() { alert("viola") }
```

Answer (score 0):

An event listener can only be a function.

```
alert("viola")
```

is *not* a function but actually `undefined`. That’s because

```
clickme.onclick=alert("viola");
```

means “assign the *return value* of `alert(…)` to `clickme.onclick`”. `alert("viola")` is being called *immediately* and the result of calling it is assigned.

The wrapper `function(){…}` actually assigns the *function* with the `alert` that is then called later.